# How to use Next-Auth for login form with axios request instead of default Form submit

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am using **Next-Auth** in my case user login but after i configs as custom page login and congrats with Form login request by method POST and it reload page when submitted. But i don't want to reload page, i wanna use axios to request data submit to APIs server when login. How i can implement this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of submitting a form via `<button type="submit">`, you can drop the whole `form` part and use the `signIn()` function from NextAuth.

Like this:

```
import { getProviders, signIn } from "next-auth/react"

export default function SignIn({ providers }) {
  return (
    <>
      {Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
        <div key={provider.name}>
          <button onClick={() => signIn(provider.id)}>
            Sign in with {provider.name}
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}
```

See: https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/pages#oauth-sign-in